# Ideals of a ring/semiring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, semiring

Define the ideals of a semiring as follows:

> A non empty subset $I$ of a semiring $S$ is said to be a left (resp. right) ideal of $S$ if:
>   (1)  $a+b\in I$ for all $a, b\in I$ and (2) $sa$ (resp. $as$) $\in I$ for any $a\in I$ and $s\in S$.

I consider that that the same definition holds true for an ideal $J$ of a ring $R$ and additionally $J$ needs to satisfy that $a-b\in J$ for all $a, b\in J$(this is needed since $R$ possesses additive inverse).

> **Conclusion:** Every ideal of a ring is also an ideal of a semiring but the converse need not be true.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You mean, if you have a ring $R$, but view it as a semiring, every ring-ideal of $R$ is also a semiring-ideal of the semiring $R$, but there are semiring-ideals of the semiring $R$ that are not ring-ideals of $R$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Yes. A  counter example  of a ring (if any) which is not a semiring would be appreciated.

Comment: Every ring is a semiring; it satisfies all the axioms. You can’t find such an example. Do you mean, an example of a semiring ideal of a ring that is not an ideal of the ring?

Comment: You did not answer the question. “Counterexample” of **what**? A ring that is not a semiring? That’s impossible. But that’s what your last comment claimed you wanted. An example of a ring $R$ and a subset $J$ that is a semiring ideal of $R$ but not a ring-ideal of $R$? I already posted one.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin It's clear now. Regret to say that typos  error made in second axiom, which i actually mean to say that left ideal and right ideal holds. So, edited accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Then what I wrote is wrong, and what Geoffrey Trang wrote is correct. And you never said “left” or “right” in your definition, so it’s absolutely wrongly stated now. You need to unaccept my answer so I can delete it.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thank you for your concern. Highly regretted for Inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a ring $R$ with unity $1$, any subset $I$ that contains zero and is closed under addition (hence an additive submonoid) and multiplication by arbitrary elements of $R$ on either side is in fact an additive subgroup (hence an ideal), because for any $i \in I$, $-i=(-1)i=i(-1)$, showing that $-i \in I$.